# How to create shared_ptr to coroutine spawned by co_spawn?

Tags: c++, boost-asio, c++-coroutine, boost-coroutine

I'm trying to implement some primitive called `co_spawn_guard` that takes the same arguments as `asio::co_spawn` runs passed coroutine and returns `shared_ptr`. This `shared_ptr` points to coroutine guard class and when this class is destroyed it emits cancellation signal of spawned coroutine.

All sounds pretty easy, but I get segfault and don't know why. I would be grateful for some hints.

[Here is a full example](https://compiler-explorer.com/z/PdGPr6aTK)

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <list>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <concepts>
#include <type_traits>
#include <memory>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>
 
#define ASIO_HAS_STD_SYSTEM_ERROR

#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/experimental/channel.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/experimental/as_tuple.hpp>

using namespace boost;


class coro_guard;

template<typename Executor, typename Awaitable, typename CompletionToken>
std::shared_ptr<coro_guard> co_spawn_guard(Executor, Awaitable&&, CompletionToken&&);
    
class coro_guard : public std::enable_shared_from_this<coro_guard>
{
public:

    template<typename Executor, typename Awaitable, typename CompletionToken>
    friend std::shared_ptr<coro_guard> co_spawn_guard(Executor, Awaitable&&, CompletionToken&&);

    template<typename... Args>
    [[nodiscard]] static std::shared_ptr<coro_guard> create(Args&&... args) 
    {
        return std::shared_ptr<coro_guard>(new coro_guard(std::forward<Args>(args)...));
    }

    coro_guard(const coro_guard&) =delete;;
    coro_guard(coro_guard&&) = delete;
    coro_guard& operator=(const coro_guard&) = delete;
    coro_guard& operator=(coro_guard&&) = delete;

    ~coro_guard()
    {
        asio::post(ex, [cancellation_signal_ptr = cancellation_signal_ptr_]()
        {
            cancellation_signal_ptr->emit(asio::cancellation_type::terminal);
        });
    }

private:
    asio::any_io_executor ex;
    std::shared_ptr<asio::cancellation_signal> cancellation_signal_ptr_;

    explicit coro_guard(asio::any_io_executor e) : ex{e}, cancellation_signal_ptr_{new asio::cancellation_signal{}}{}
};


template<typename Awaitable>
asio::awaitable<void> internal_coro(Awaitable&& a, std::shared_ptr<asio::cancellation_signal> ptr)
{
    std::cout<<"DEBUG internal_coro enter\n";
    co_await std::move(a);
    std::cout<<"DEBUG internal_coro exit\n";
    co_return;
}

template<typename Executor, typename Awaitable, typename CompletionToken>
std::shared_ptr<coro_guard> co_spawn_guard(Executor ex, Awaitable&& a, CompletionToken&& token)
{
    std::shared_ptr<coro_guard> guard =coro_guard::create(ex);
    asio::co_spawn(ex, internal_coro(std::move(a), guard->cancellation_signal_ptr_), asio::bind_cancellation_slot(guard->cancellation_signal_ptr_->slot(), std::forward<CompletionToken>(token)));
    return guard;
}

asio::awaitable<void> test_coro()
{
    std::cout<<"DEBUG internal_coro enter\n";
    std::cout<<"DEBUG internal_coro exit\n";
    co_return;
}

int main()
{
    asio::io_context io_context;

    auto ptr =co_spawn_guard(io_context.get_executor(), test_coro(), asio::detached);

    io_context.run();
    std::cout<<"dupa\n";
}
```

Comment: I think that "co_await std::move(a);" actually produce segfault, but i might be wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Coros cannot take their arguments by reference unless their lifetime is guaranteed. Change this:

```
asio::awaitable<void> internal_coro(Awaitable& a, std::shared_ptr<asio::cancellation_signal> ptr) {
```

To

```
asio::awaitable<void> internal_coro(Awaitable a, std::shared_ptr<asio::cancellation_signal> ptr) {
```

Also, `std::move` on a "universal reference" is unsafe. Use `std::forward` instead here:

```
asio::co_spawn(ex, internal_coro(std::move(a), guard->cancellation_signal_ptr_),
               asio::bind_cancellation_slot(guard->cancellation_signal_ptr_->slot(),
                                            std::forward<CompletionToken>(token)));
```

Should be

```
asio::co_spawn(ex, internal_coro(std::forward<Awaitable>(a), guard->cancellation_signal_ptr_),
               asio::bind_cancellation_slot(guard->cancellation_signal_ptr_->slot(),
                                            std::forward<CompletionToken>(token)));
```

Finally, I feel this is probably all a bit over-complicated and has some glaring design flaws. For example, you suggest you accept arbitrary completion tokens on `co_spawn_guard`. However most of them will not make any sense since you neglect to use the value returned by `asio::co_spawn`.

Comment: thank you @sehe for your great answer! I think idea is simple (if shared_ptr dies then cancel signal is emitted) by implementation is indeed complicated. I create  [another more straightforward example](https://godbolt.org/z/EThzb4jzc). How about this one?